# Make jwt token expired after one of the user's property has changed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jwt

is it possible to make jwt token expired after one of the user's property has changed ( for example - activated: false or role: [ADMIN] )? Or maybe there is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the source of information by which you determine that the JWT has become stale?  This is a critical piece of information here.

Comment: For example: user was promoted to admin or maybe it was dactivated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically a JWT expires only when the expiry date for that token passes.  But this doesn't mean that a JWT cannot expire logically for other reasons.  One example would be that your Node application receives a request with a valid JWT, but the token belongs to a user whose account was recently deactivated.  The workflow might look something like this:

- Your Node app receives the JWT
- It decrypts the JWT, and extracts the username
- Then it queries a user table in your database to check the status of the account
- Having discovered that the account is not active, your Node app redirects to the login page with an error message

It is generally up to you to determine how to proceed with a JWT.  The JWT just protects the token from being manipulated by the user.